# Socket programming in C

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

Ok, so I'm trying to get some UDP code working and I'm barely green when it comes to network programming using C. I'm using the sample file from [here](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/examples/listener.c)

Basically I'm just listening for incoming UDP packets on a given port and then I want to send some data back the same way. Below is the relevant part.

At this point the socket is set up and bound to a port of choice and awaits incoming packets:

```
printf("GSProxy: waiting to recvfrom...\n");

addr_len = (socklen_t) sizeof their_addr;
if ((numbytes = recvfrom(sockfd, buf, MAXBUFLEN-1 , 0,
    (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &addr_len)) == -1) { // argument 6 gives a warning but is correct int
    perror("recvfrom");
    exit(1);
}

printf("GSProxy: got packet from %s\n", 
inet_ntop(their_addr.ss_family, 
    get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)&their_addr), s, sizeof s));
printf("GSProxy: packet is %d bytes long\n", numbytes);
buf[numbytes] = '\0';
printf("GSProxy: packet contains \"%s\"\n", buf);

char retmsg[] = "Hello!";
if ((numbytes = sendto(sockfd, retmsg, 7, 0, 
    (struct sockaddr *) &their_addr, &addr_len)) == -1) {
    perror("GSPProxy: sendto");
    exit(1);
}

printf("GSProxy: Sent %i bytes.\n", numbytes);
```

I just want to send the "Hello!" string right back to the sender.

This fails with Error "`GSPProxy: sendto: File name too long`". Which is the [ENAMETOOLONG] error code, as far is I can tell.

But... what the ** does it mean? What file? What is too long?

Is it that I can't reuse the socket to send data back, or have I just made another newb mistake?

Best regards,

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should not be passing the address of the socket structure length to `sendto()` - it requires the actual length (i.e., `"addr_len"`, not `"&addr_len"`).

The reason you pass the *address* of the length to `recvfrom()` is that it is changed by that function if the real address happens to be shorter.

In other words, replace:

```
if ((numbytes = sendto (sockfd, retmsg, 7, 0,
    (struct sockaddr *) &their_addr, &addr_len)) == -1) {
```

with:

```
if ((numbytes = sendto (sockfd, retmsg, 7, 0,
    (struct sockaddr *) &their_addr, addr_len)) == -1) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Erm, at a minimum the '&addr_len' you passed in sendto probably should have not been passed by address: ie: should have just been addr_len.